# Issue using "where" in parse.com rest api - query constraints

Tags: api, rest, curl, parse-platform

Using the rest API for parse.com, however, struggling to get the where clause to work properly. I've read through their documentation, but don't understand why I'm not getting results. I get a 200 status, but no results.

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/companies?limit=10000&where=%7B%22company_id%22%3A%221%22%7D" \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 444444" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: 444444"
```

Basing this on their query constraints found [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#queries-query-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 444444" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 444444" \
-G \
--data-urlencode "where={\"company_id\":\"1\"}" \
--data-urlencode "limit=10000" \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/companies
```

**Note:** Either consider using REST key, or change relevant line to master key.

---

Additionally, you have a nice curl request generator under `API Console` tab in your Parse project, and the URL to it will look sth like:

```
https://www.parse.com/apps/<PROJECT_NAME>/api_console
```

Comment: In my code above, if I remove the company_id constraint, the limit works fine. company_id is listed as a string. Do I need to do something more to get it to work?